# What sort of class does BeginInvoke return? How can I use it to call EndInvoke?

Tags: c#

I'm working my way bottom up through ASP.net, and I was setting up an old school delegate pattern:

```
    public delegate void ProcessRequestDelegate(HttpContext context);

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        ProcessRequestDelegate asyncDelegate = new ProcessRequestDelegate(ProcessRequest);
        return asyncDelegate.BeginInvoke(context, cb, extraData);
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
       //?? profit?
    }
```

But I realized, I don't know what to cast the `IAsyncResult result` to in the `EndProcessRequest` function. I tried:

```
    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // Compiler error because this is dumb
        ((ProcessRequestDelegate)result).EndInvoke(result);
    }
```

but obviously you can't cast result to a delegate. So what is the proper way to end the invocation. And more generally, what sort of class does `Delegate.BeginInvoke` return?

**Update**

So I tried this out:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        IAsyncResult result = BeginStuff("something", null, null);
        IAsyncResult result2 = BeginStuff("something else", null, null);

        EndStuff(result);
        EndStuff(result2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Action<String> act = delegate(String str)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        Console.WriteLine("This seems to work");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    };

    static Action<String> act2 = delegate(String str) { };

    public static IAsyncResult BeginStuff(String data, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    {
        return Program.act.BeginInvoke(data, callback, state);
    }

    public static void EndStuff(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // This works fine no matter how many times BeginInvoke is called
        Program.act.EndInvoke(result);

        // This however will fail, because the delegate that began the invocation 
        // is not the same as the one that ends it.
        Program.act2.EndInvoke(result);
    }
```

and it seems to work fine. As long as `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` are called using the same delegate, the runtime handles the rest (I guess that's what the IAsyncResult is for). If you try to end using a different delegate though, it will give you a kind reminder not to do that.

**Another Update**

I found a better-er way to do this:

```
public void Operation()
{
    throw new FaultException<FrieldyError>(new FrieldyError("returned with this error"));
}

public IAsyncResult BeginOperation(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    return ((Action)Operation).BeginInvoke(callback, state);
}

public void EndOperation(IAsyncResult result)
{
    ((Action)Operation).EndInvoke(result);
}
```

Since you just need to be using the same type of delegate, you can use one of the pre-existing ones and it works fine. No need to declare a local/private delegate of your own.

Useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldnt matter to you what the concrete class returned by `Delegate.BeginInvoke` is, whatever it is the interface provides all you need in order to wait for its completion (using a `WaitHandle` or a polling technique [[examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2e08f6yc.aspx)]) and call`EndInvoke`.

In addition, you've specified an `AsyncCallback` parameter, wouldnt you just pass `EndProcessRequest` to that?

eg,

```
this.BeginProcessRequest(
        HttpContext.Current, 
        this.EndProcessRequest, 
        "My extra data");
```

---

**Edit after comments:**

If you're implementing `IHttpAsyncHandler` as your comments describe, you should have even less problems, as you can store the delegate instance as a member of your class

```
public class ProcessRequestAsyncHandler ; IHttpAsyncHandler 
{
   private  ProcessRequestDelegate asyncDelegate;

   public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        asyncDelegate = new ProcessRequestDelegate(ProcessRequest);
        return asyncDelegate.BeginInvoke(context, cb, extraData);
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        asyncDelegate.EndInvoke(result);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       // Do something long-running
    }
}
```

Reference:

- http://madskristensen.net/post/How-to-use-the-IHttpAsyncHandler-in-ASPNET.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.isreusable.aspx

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. But I'm not invoking BeginProcessRequest, IIS is. I'm just implementing the Begin/End pattern because that's what IHttpAsyncHandler requires.

Comment: I've seen this pattern before, but I'm confused, wouldn't setting `asyncDelegate` to something overwrite the existing information? If I then call `asyncDelegate.EndInvoke` does that mean I can only end the most recent request? What happens to previous requests? Obviously, something I don't understand about this structure.

Comment: @sircodesalot - you're missing that IIS will create a new *instance* of the handler for each request it processes. Look at the example linked below the code - do you think that will only transmit the most recently requested file? Or that 2 simultaneous requests might transfer the wrong file to the wrong user? (answer: No - IIS sorts it out)

Comment: @sircodesalot - My bad, you need to override `IsReusable` and return false. Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.isreusable.aspx

Comment: But if you have to set IsReusable to false, that seems to maybe confirm my suspicion? If you have to generate multiple instances, of course it can be async, but I submit that doesn't seem to solve the primary issue.

Comment: So I set up a simple example that uses the delegate construction approach above, and it seems to work fine. As long as the delegate that begins the invocation is the same as the one that ends it, the runtime seems to be happy (no matter how many begin-invocations you make).

Comment: Actually, one more thing (small discovery I made). Instead of re-instanciating the `asyncDelegate` it makes sense to instantiate it once (at declaration) and then keep reusing it (see my example above).

Comment: Updated my answer. Found an even cleaner way to do this. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it as an [AsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult.aspx) object. This contains properties such as your delegate and `AsyncState` (the object you passed in `extraData`). To get your delegate, you can try this

```
((ProcessRequestDelegate)((AsyncResult)result).AsyncDelegate)).EndInvoke();
```

The [AsyncDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult.asyncdelegate.aspx) property gets the delegate which invoked the async call.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a good idea to make assumption that the returned object is AsyncResult. Maybe it can be some other object that implements IAsyncResult interface ? Otherwise the signature of the method would state that its AsyncResult that is returned.

Comment: This is crazy obscure, but it does work. Also, although I tend to agree with Petar that it's bad practice to assume, there is only one entry point for this Begin/End pattern, so it's _technically_ safe to assume that it will be the ProcessRequestDelegate, though I do think a more general solution (i.e. one that works for all delegates) would be cool. +1 though for a good working solution!

Comment: Yes, you're both right in that it assumes the casting type for this example. To make it generic, you could try making the callback generic. I haven't tried this, but there's an example here https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/562850-How-to-retreive-generic-type

Comment: How would you skip the explicit casting to call `EndInvoke`?

Comment: I read the article, but I think your first answer is more correct. I'm not the one building the delegate, this is part of the `IHttpAsyncHandler` interface (for asp), so I have to follow it's structure (unless I don't?), so I think you were closer with your original answer.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that you were implementing the IHttpAsyncHandler interface. In that case, I think JamieC's updated answer seems to be on the right track.

Comment: I really like your answer, in fact I think it's potentially more elegant than setting up a local instance of a delegate, if only it weren't so massive. Appreciate the helpt though. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer. Found an even cleaner way to do this. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, it seems you will have to do it that way. Here is what you could do:

```
public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    ProcessRequestDelegate del = (ProcessrequestDelegate) result.AsyncState;
    object item = del.EndInvoke(result)
}
```

Loo [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/Delegates_and_Events%E2%80%94Callback_Methods) at this article.

Comment: Definite thanks for the effort, but this won't work because AsyncState is 'contextual information' given by the user when they call BeginInvoke. In my example above, the `result.AsyncState` would be filled in with whatever the user (in this case IIS) fills into the the `extraData` argument.